public key not found
I'm in the process of upgrading a large project dependencies, and I've been changing everything. When trying to upgrade the Eclipse target platform dependencies, I get this error in the .target file
problems occurred while resolving the target contents
pulic key not found for 700e4f39bc0536

here my target file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="LetterGen 8.0.0 Target Platform" sequenceNumber="129">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release/17.0.3/"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.base.feature.group" version="17.0.3.v20220515-1416"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.base.stripped.feature.group" version="17.0.3.v20220515-1416"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.stripped.feature.group" version="17.0.3.v20220515-1416"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group" version="17.0.3.v20220515-1416"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.feature.group" version="17.0.3.v20220515-1416"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.feature.group" version="17.0.3.v20220515-1416"/>
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.4.44.v20210927/"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jetty.bundles.f.feature.group" version="9.4.44.v20210927"/>
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-09/202409111000/"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.group" version="3.15.2.v20240709-1538"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="3.15.2.v20240812-1535"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.39.0.v20240731-0952"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.23.1400.v20240820-0604"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.gef.sdk.feature.group" version="5.5.0.202311221639"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="4.33.0.v20240903-0618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj.feature.group" version="3.7.4.v202308161955"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.31.0.v202405130132"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.34.0.v202404170147"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.xsd.sdk.feature.group" version="2.37.0.v20240604-0832"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>

I've tried to change the software from this
https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/202112081000/

to this
https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-09/202409111000/

when I faced the issue.
I tried to create a GPG certificate, but it's not the problem.

Do you get also "pulic key not found" if you use everywhere version="0.0.0" (the version is already given by the location) and use only https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-09 (without /202409111000/)? The public key that is not found is probably the one to verify the signing of the artifacts. Do you use Tycho for building and if so, it is up to date (4.0.10)?
